# number is not a function upon JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver, appium

Upon executing:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: longClick", new HashMap<String, Double>() {{  put("x", (double)30); put("y", (double)50);put("touchCount", (double)1);  put("duration", 5.0); }});
```

I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ERROR running Appium command: number is not a function
```

Any idea what went wrong here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `executeScript` expect Javascript code as the parameter?

Comment: @donfuxx  :- With Appium we can pass mobile gestures arguments to executeScript as per the below link ,
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/e28273acad649d813ccf826c7416cd62ac4f86b3/sample-code/examples/java/testng/src/test/java/com/saucelabs/appium/SimpleTest.java

Comment: What type of element is being acted on? If it's a WebElement, you would just call .click(). The code you are trying to use is only for native elements.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this??? Stuck at the same place.